# Example of Noetherian domain which is not Zariski domain

Tags: abstract-algebra

The definition of Zariski ring is [here]{https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zariski_ring}. A Noetherian local domain is a Zariski ring but I was wondering if there is a Noetherian domain which is not Zariski ring. Here domain means I assume it has the identity.

Thanks, in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Counterexamples" are plentiful and can be found from the definition. Namely, let $A$ be *any* non-local domain, $I \subseteq A$ an ideal which is not contained in the Jacobson radical (for example a maximal ideal of $A$) and equip $A$ with the $I$-adic topology.